# df = df.reset_index(drop=True) выдает ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_drop = df.drop([0,2,4])


df_drop = df_drop.reset_index(drop=True)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Необходимо заресетить индекс по нулевой оси.

Comment: Вы понимаете смысл сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: Если честно, не очень понимаю, почему у меня df был нормальным объектом, а df_drop вдруг стал NonType

Comment: Сначала стоит разобраться почему вы получаете None

Comment: Для этого и написал здесь, чтобы добрые люди помогли разобраться :)

Answer (score 4):

Не воспроизводится. Даже если в исходном датафрейме не останется вообще данных после удаления строк через `drop`, такую ошибку нельзя будет получить. Единственная возможность получить именно такую ошибку именно в этом месте - это использовать в функции `drop` параметр `inplace=True`, при использовании этого параметра `Pandas` записывает результат обратно в датафрейм, а функция возвращает значение `None`, которое и присваивается в итоге в `df_drop`:

```
df_drop = df.drop([0,2,4], inplace=True)
```

> ```
>       5 df_drop = df.drop([0,2,4], inplace=True)
> ----> 6 df_drop = df_drop.reset_index(drop=True)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
> ```

Либо у вас ещё есть какие-то строки между `drop` и `reset_index`, которые вы нам не показали.

Comment: да, судя по всему, так и есть. Дело в том, то в первоначальном варианте, использовался параметр inplace=True, но затем я его убрал, т.к. задача изменилась. После перезагрузки кернела вроде все исправилось. Правда перед перезагрузкой кернела проверил df, она была исходной без дропнутых строк. Спасибо большое -  сам бы не догадался :)